# Arranging Items Alphabetically in Vertical Columns

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a list of words, which should be arranged in alphabetical order, but "vertical".

This is how it looks now:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| EEE | FFF | GGG | HHH |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Every word is embed in a `<td>` inside a `<table>`, and it's always limited to 4 items per table row.

How could I display these words vertically, like this:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| AAA | EEE | and | 
+-----+-----+-----+
| BBB | FFF |  so |  
+-----+-----+-----+
| CCC | GGG |  on |  
+-----+-----+-----+
| DDD | HHH |     | 
+-----+-----+-----+
```

The amount of words is dynamically controlled, it could get more/less at any time.

This is an older project developed in classic ASP, but I could also work with ideas coming from VB.NET.

The current codes is the following (cut down to the important parts):

```
do until recordSet.EOF
    temphtml = temphtml & " <tr>" & vbcrlf 'this is where i collect all the <tr> and <td>
    for i = 1 to 4
        tempItem = recordSet("NameOfItem")
        temphtml = temphtml & tempbez & vbcrlf 
        recordSet.MoveNext
        if recordSet.EOF then exit for
    next
    temphtml = temphtml & " </tr>" & vbcrlf
loop
```

Comment: What you want is crystal clear. Can you please show us what have you tried to accomplish such a goal?

Comment: What you need is the [The Magical `Mod` Function](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19315/The-Magical-Mod-Function.htm) *(especially the bit at the end called "Mod to the Rescue")*

Comment: @varocarbas You are right , I forgot that part. I edited the opening post with the current state of the code.

Comment: I don't see any reference to before/after. What is this code supposed to be doing? The information have to be retrieved by following the structure in the first sample and converted into the second one. Logically, your code doesn't need to work perfectly; but at least show that you have done some effort by your own. How is such a conversion expected to be performed? How are you storing the initial information? And the final version?

Answer (score 1):

Using WebForm VB.NET. Add a server-side Table in your aspx page:

```
<asp:Table ID="tableWords" runat="server"></asp:Table>
```

VB.NET

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim tableRows As New List(Of TableRow)()
    Dim maxRows As Integer = 4
    Dim index As Integer = 0

    Dim recordSet As New DataSet()
    ' TODO: get the items from the database
    Dim nbItems As Integer = recordSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count

    For i As Integer = 0 To nbItems - 1
        Dim item As String = recordSet.Tables(0).Rows(i)("NameOfItem").ToString()

        If i < maxRows Then
            Dim tr As New TableRow()
            Dim td As New TableCell()
            td.Text = item
            tr.Cells.Add(td)
            tableRows.Add(tr)
        Else
            If i Mod maxRows - 1 = 0 Then
                index = 0
            End If
            Dim td As New TableCell()
            td.Text = item
            tableRows(index).Cells.Add(td)
            index += 1
        End If
    Next

    Dim cellsToAdd As Integer = maxRows - (nbItems Mod maxRows)
    Dim startIndex As Integer = maxRows - cellsToAdd

    If cellsToAdd < maxRows Then
        For i As Integer = startIndex To cellsToAdd
            Dim td As New TableCell()
            td.Text = "&nbsp;"
            tableRows(i).Cells.Add(td)
        Next
    End If

    tableItems.Rows.AddRange(tableRows.ToArray)
End Sub
```

Edit: Using a DataSet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as you've doubtless discovered, is that html table syntax is row-by-row, not column-by-column. If you need to do columns first, then rows, then you need to jump through a few extra hoops.

```
Dim row(3), counter, r
Const RowCount = 4
...
counter = 0
Do Until recordSet.EOF
    r = counter Mod RowCount '- figure out which row we're at
    row(r) = row(r) & "<td>" & recordSet("NameOfItem") & "</td>"
    counter = counter + 1
    recordSet.Movenext
Loop
If counter Mod RowCount > 0 Then '- add empty cells to any incomplete rows
    For r = Counter Mod RowCount to RowCount - 1
        row(r) = row(r) & "<td></td>"
    Next
End If
For r = 0 to RowCount - 1 '- assemble the table
    row(r) = "<tr>" & row(r) & "</tr>" & vbCrLf
    temphtml = temphtml & row(r)
Next
```

The above is quick-and-dirty (read: untested) code, but it should get you on the right track. Also, if you need a header row on the table, you'll need to keep track of the number of columns somehow.